# How to refresh gridview when I use sqldatasource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web, multilingual

I am developing an asp.net website .this web site is multilangual. some section of this website is static and some of them are dynamic and get their data from database.so in this project I have a master page and i have default page which is filled with a gridview that is feed by a sqldatasource.so when I change language to english I want gridview to refresh and retrive english data from database and display in gridview .i dont know how to do this please help me

```
 string language = "fa-IR";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        HttpCookie LangCookies = new HttpCookie("Language");
        LangCookies.Value = language;
        LangCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(LangCookies);


<li style="text-align:center; width:130px;vertical-align:top">
                    <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">فارسی</asp:LinkButton></div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">ENG</asp:LinkButton></div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Is this indented to be an AJAX call though javascript, or a page refresh thing? Please also include the code that you have that is not working as you expect.

Comment: Is There any way to do this without AJAX????

Comment: What triggers the language change? Does the user click a button to change the language?

Comment: <li style="text-align:center; width:130px;vertical-align:top">
                    <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">فارسی</asp:LinkButton></div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">ENG</asp:LinkButton></div>
                </li>

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code , so I'll tell you theoretically how it  can be perform.

You need minimum  two page for this

1)Main page

```
<div id="#gridview-div">
//here render your partial page
</div>
```

2) Partial page

```
<table id="gridview">
</table>
```

Then using ajax you should make call to server that will give you back data(Partial view) and than place this data to your gridview-div.Here is some example how to pass data into div [jQuery html() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since changing the language will change only columns name or header You can store all names or headers of grid columns with corrsponding language in a table so you can build multi language web site

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a little more implementation detail. Avoid overly general answers.